# Установка приложений в Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, debian, установка

Осваиваю сабж.

Понятно применение пакетных менеджеров вроде Синаптика, но, к примеру хочу установить Qt 4.8.4 - т.е. придется через make и make install (m&mi).

Но возникает первый вопрос - после m&mi - файлы сорцов можно удалить?

Дальше - после установки - как мне запустить установленное приложение? К примеру тот же QtCreator - кде найти его лаунчер(вроде так называется)?

Дальше - хотелось бы удалить установленный пакет - который раньше установил его из исходный файлов - как удалить - я понимаю что ***apt-get remove "имя пакета"*** - но как узнать имя данного пакета?

И кстати гугл выдал кучу воды - ничего конкретного в качестве ответа не нашел. Надеюсь пинать не будете

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Эту проблему вам поможет решить [CheckInstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/download.php).

Эта утилита позволит вам создать родной пакет (не важно deb или, к примеру, rpm).

После чего вы сможете установить этот пакет через нативный package manager

```
# dpkg -i your_package.deb
```

Чтобы удалить этот пакет можно также воспользоваться dpkg

```
# dpkg -r your_package
```

Чтобы найти куда установился пакет можно посмотреть список всех его файлов

```
# dpkg -L bash
```

но нам, по идее, нужно только то что имеет в пути `/bin`

```
# dpkg -L bash | grep /bin
```

примерный вывод последней команды

```
/bin/bin/bash/usr/bin/usr/bin/bashbug/usr/bin/clear_console/bin/rbash/bin/sh
```

Comment: Хмм... суть уловил. Получается что "исполняемые" файлы для выполнения приложения находятся в папке bin (аналог Program Files из винды)?

Comment: Вроде того. Есть еще папки `sbin`,  не хочу врать, но по-моему это то ли `secure bin`, то ли `system bin`.

Comment: @areshin, а еще есть `/usr/local/bin`, `/opt/bin`, `~/.rvm/bin` и куча всяких разных `bin`-ов, не будьте так категоричны.Да и в PATH установленного приложения может не быть.

Comment: Я о том и писал, но убрал уже! Потому, что сообразил, что если он не от рута ставил, а от юзера, то это должно быть в /usr/local/bin !

Comment: скорее всего это все будет в `/opt/qt`

Comment: А и не будем гадать! Там в make.conf надо смотреть, что там по дефолту.

Comment: Блин, пока мы тут трындели, уже Qt 5.01 вышел: http://qt-project.org/downloads

Answer (score 2):

Что и где лежит можно найти через locate или slocate.

Answer (score 0):

> Т.е. придется через `make` и `make install`.

Ну почему сразу "придётся"? Вообще-то есть альтернативные методы, это же `Linux`. Вот тут уже описывал [Установка программ в Linux: тарболы.](http://freeprogrammer.ru/index.php/articles/305-installinlinux-tarbol).

Comment: А можно ман как вы проделаете тоже самое по SSH на сервере? и желательно чтобы программа была юниксовая, не скайп.

Comment: 1. с помощью scp затащу на сервер нужный тарбол2. распакую его, сделаю всё как описывал в статье, изменив только название тарбола.Вот вроде бы и весь ман. Хотите подробнее? Тогда давайте конкретную программу и лучше уже в скайпе или аське пообщаться (skype-danildan75work, icq - 345458854)